Absolute continuity of time-dependent inner product
I made this post earlier, but I think it would be best to split it up into multiple questions which is the aim of this question.
I am following a proof of a simplified version of the Aubin-Lions lemma from the textbook The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations by Robinson, Rodrigo, and Sadowski which says:

Aubin-Lions Lemma; simple version Let $\Omega$ be the torus $\mathbb{T}^3$ or a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If the sequence $(u_n)$ is uniformly bounded in $L^q(0, T; V)$, $q > 1$, and the partial derivatives $\partial_t u _n$ are uniformly bounded in $L^p(0, T; V^*)$, $p > 1$, then there exist $u \in L^q(0, T; H)$ and a subsequence of $(u_n)$ that converges strongly to $u$ in $L^q(0, T; H)$.

Here

$H$ is the set of $L^2$ functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^3$ (the 3-torus) to $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are divergence free
$V := H \cap (H^1)^3$ where $(H^1)^3$ is the function space $H^1 \times H^1 \times H^1$ (either on $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^3$) and where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$. In other words, $V$ is the set of all divergence free vector fields whose components are all in $H^1$
$V^*$ is the dual of $V$
$A$ is the Stokes operator whose action is defined as $Au = \mathbb{P}\Delta u$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the Leray projector and $\Delta$ is the Laplacian
$\mathcal{N}$ is the set of eigenfunctions of the Stokes operator, which form a basis for $H(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is equal to $\mathbb{T}^3$ or a smooth bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$
The inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the $L^2$ inner product over $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{T}^3$
$u_n, u: \Omega \textrm{ (or } \mathbb{T}^3) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

They also refer to the following lemma in their proof. Here $X$ is a Banach space:

Lemma 1.31 Suppose that $u, g \in L^1(0, T; X)$. Then the following are equivalent

$u$ has weak time derivative $g$;
there exists $\xi \in X$ such that $$u(t) = \xi + \int_0^t g(s) ds \quad \textrm{for almost every } t \in [0,T];$$
for every $f \in X^*$ $$\frac{d}{dt} \langle f, u \rangle = \langle f, g \rangle,$$ where the time derivative is taken in the weak sense.

In particular, if (1)-(3) hold then $u$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function from $[0,T]$ into $X$.

Their proof begins as:

We will first obtain bounds on finite-dimensional projections of the sequence $(u_n)$. To this end let us consider $\langle u_n(t), a_j\rangle$, where $a_j \in \mathcal{N}$ is an eigenfunction of the Stokes operator corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$. From Lemma 1.31 we can deduce that $\langle u_n (t), a_j \rangle$ is absolutely continuous with $\frac{d}{dt}\langle u_n, a_j \rangle = \langle \partial_t u_n, a_j \rangle$ almost everywhere on $[0, T]$ so $$\langle u_n(s), a_j \rangle = \langle u_n(s^*), a_j \rangle + \int_{s^*}^s \langle \partial_t u_n, a_j \rangle$$ for almost every $s \in [0, T]$.


My question is how does absolute continuity of $\langle u_n(t), a_j \rangle$ follow from Lemma 1.31 above?
